# how to differentiate between valid and invalid NALU in AVCC?

Tags: video, video-processing, h.264, mpeg-4, nalu

I have a mp4 file that has only video data without moov atom. I have parsed the SPS, PPS. I'm trying to decode the video frames and NALU in this data. When I process each byte of this data to find NALU, I'm getting a false NALU because in RBSP data there are some bytes which are similar as NALU header (0x65, 0x01, 0x21, 0x61). The video data is in AVCC format, not in Annex B so I cannot find the start code to know the starting of the NALU. Is there anything with i can compare the NALU size to find out that it is a valid NALU or not?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have MP4 'mdat' atoms with some h.264 payload data in each one. Or maybe you have [RFC 6184 payload data](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184). You didn't say.

You should look at the first 'mdat' atom to look for your SPS and PPS NALUs.

That 'mdat' atom probably looks something like this.

```
 ---length-- m  d  a  t
 00 00 07 a9 6d 64 61 74 

    ---length-- SPS atom......... NALU id 7 ................  
    00 00 00 0f 67 42 c0 14 8c 8d 41 42 2f 2c 03 c2 21 1a 80

    ---length-- PPS atom...  NALU id 8
    00 00 00 04 68 ce 3c 80 

    ---length-- pix ... 
    00 00 00 ed 65 b8 00 04 00 00 09 fd b9 48 88...
```

In other words, each NALU in the 'mdat' starts with a four-byte length, then the NALU.  It can also be a three-byte or two-byte length (two-byte is pretty doggone useless). [RFC 6184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184)'s definition of [Single Time Aggregation Units](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184#section-5.7.1) calls for four-byte lengths.

If the stream is in annexB, each NALU starts with either `00 00 01` or `00 00 00 01` rather than a length.

SPS and PPS NALUs don't have a fixed size. And they're hard to parse because their contents are coded using a variable-length scheme called [exponential Golomb coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential-Golomb_coding). So your best bet, if you possibly can, is to find their boundaries and treat them as opaque, but variable-length, chunks of bytes.

I put together [some Javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/h264-interp-utils) to parse SPS and PPS NALUs because I had a similar problem to yours.

Comment: I have parsed the SPS and PPS NALU using exp Golomb code. I want to verify the next IDR and non-IDR NALUs specifically NALU type 1 and 5 are valid. Your javascript  link is directing to wikipedia.

Comment: Oops. please excuse the incorrect link. Fixed.

Comment: I went through your Javascript to parse SPS and PPS NALU..I already completed this part, I need to parse next I frame and IDR NALU. Can we check a NALU with type 1 or 5 that it has valid content, same as you are checking for SPS, PPS NAlU in the constructor?